I restore backup from itunes, whatsapp is on original space 12gb (chat history) i login it deletes all chats and space go down to 0?
I have an issue. I’m trying to resolve for over a week now. I lost my phone and I have a backup from iTunes when I restore from this backup and I cannot restore my WhatsApp chat history. What happens is I restore the back up I log into WhatsApp it deletes all the chat history and the WhatsApp size goes from the original space which was 13 GB to almost 500 MB and I find no chats when I login.
This deletion happens once i log in otherwise it appears in the old storage 13 gb
